# Android Studio prompts "Class requires API level 24 (current min is 1)" when trying to use Java 1.8 class

Tags: android, api, google-app-engine, java-8

I am trying to use the java.util.function Consumer class from Java 1.8, but Android Studio is prompting

Class requires API level 24 (current min is 1)

App Engine shouldn't have anything to do with the Android API, so I don't know why it's prompting that.

Does anyone know how I can overcome the error?  Thank!

Edit (Complete Gradle):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.38'
  }
}

repositories {
  jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

dependencies {
  appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.38'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:1.9.38'
  testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:1.9.38'
  compile group: 'com.googlecode.junit-toolbox', name: 'junit-toolbox', version: '1.5'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.38'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.38'
  compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.5'
  compile 'org.json:json:20151123'
  compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
  compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2'
  compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
  compile 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.4'
  compile 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1'
  compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev66-1.21.0'
}

appengine {
  downloadSdk = true
  appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
  }
  endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
  }

  httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"

  jvmFlags = ['-Ddatastore.backing_store="/Users/jwu/StudioProjects/ProjectBoon2/local_db.bin']
}
```

Comment: Can you post your gradle ?

Comment: Hi Johnny, were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

In the `build.gradle` file of the android module set the value of `minSdkVersion` to 24.

```
android {

    ... other values ...

    defaultConfig {

        ... other values ... 

        minSdkVersion 24

        ... other values ...
    }

    ... other values ...

}
```

That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Edit you gradle to use API level 24 and then sync the project.

Comment: Why would App Engine care what API Level is being used? Plus, Consumer class if from java 1.8 (it's not directly related to the API level)...unless I am missing something.

Comment: maybe it's not about java 1.8. Anyway that's what it says so you should use API 24.